# push notification configuration helios

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, helios

I am trying to use [Helios](https://github.com/helios-framework) to send push notifications to my app. The project does not offer any description on where and how to place the .pem file(apns certificate used for push notification). I was hoping that someone on stackoverflow might have experience using helios as a backend for APNs. Some help will be really appreciated.I have hosted the project on heroku and when my app tries to register for Push notifications using [oribiter](https://github.com/mattt/Orbiter) gem it fails and gives the following error:

```
Registration Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 500" UserInfo=0x1d871c30 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated the [Helios](https://github.com/helios-framework) gem using `--edge` and this resolved this same issue for me.

I did not need to use `.env` setting.

Answer (score 2):

Under the trunk, Helios is using Houston for APNS client, it takes a couple of ENV variables to setup paths, take a look at [this line](https://github.com/mattt/houston/blob/master/lib/houston/client.rb#L27) in source.

Comment: So basically I just have to add the following line to my .env file:

APN_CERTIFICATE = "path/to/certificate"

Will that be all? and yes thank you, this is the closest I have come to having this issue since yesterday.